# Past simple vs present perfect vs past continouos

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Can You tell me please, if explanations/questions for those sentences are correct?

1. **Present simple**: I break my legs. => (explanation) I do it all the time, from time to time, it's my habit or sth what occurs from time to time.
2. **Present Continouos**: I am breaking a leg. => (explanation) Now as we are speaking, I'm trying so hard to do it.
3. **Past simple 1**: I broke a leg. => (explanation - question?)  Is my leg now broken, or is it already healed and healthy, or we don't know that? Is it correct to use past simple without a time reference from the past?
4. **Past simple 2**: I broke a leg **two years ago**. => (explanation - question?)  Is my leg now broken, or is it already healed and healthy, or we don't know that?
5. **Past simple 3**: I broke a leg **yesterday**. => (explanation - question?)  Is my leg now broken(**it must be!**), or is it already healed and healthy, or we don't know that?
6. **Present Perfect**: I have broken a leg. => (explanation)  My leg is broken right as we are speaking. I did it some time ago (we don't know when exactly)
7. **Past Continuous**: I was breaking my leg. => (explanation)  I was in the act of doing it.

Regards!

Comment: It's an odd choice of example, but your explanations are more or less correct.  I say "more or less" because "breaking a leg" is not normally something which is described in some of these tenses.

Comment: I agree with Andrew - grammatical tenses don't really tell us very much about whether a past action is resolved or not.  It might be clearer if you used an example like "open the door", because "I opened the door" should make it clearer that the simple past says nothing about whether the door is open right now.

Comment: The question should be changed to something that makes better sense. I am breaking my leg now? Who would even say that.

Comment: Pablo, I already answered your question.  If you want a better answer, ask a better question.

Answer (score 0):

Past simple 1, 2, and 3.
Sentences with the past tense mostly describes only the fact in the past and do not describe anything after that. You can not know the leg is still broken. When someone says to you " I broke a leg yesterday.", you do not have any information about today, but by common sense, you are sure that the leg is still broken.

Sometimes, the past simple tense describes habits in the past as the present tense dose at present.

The present perfect tense can use right after things happen. In addition, you can express experiences, too; in this case, events described could happen long time ago.